# How to use Hibernate to check if the necessary privilegies are correctly set in a multiple database application?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, architecture

I need to add a verification in an installer to assure that the current user have privileges to for example add tables and indexes. 
 This application uses Hibernate in the data layer and the installer allows to choose between `Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL and MySQL` .  I wonder if it is possible to use Hibernate to check it independently of the chosen database or if I will have to write code to each of the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply try to create the table (or do whatever you need) and check if it succeeds or not. if not then you will get an exception. if it's not enough and you need very precise information about the type of error then you will probably have to do it independently for each db

Comment: I did more or less this, but still a problem: I create the table and the index, add some information for the that, update and delete this information. It test all the necessary privilegies that I need. However, can be that the user do not have DROP privilege, so the table and the index will stay in the database without necessity. I am currently trying to solve this "detail".

Comment: just think is it worth the effort. grants can be revoked any time, even after your application successfully checked for all permissions. so 'what should be tested' may be a business decision rather than a technical one